# MySQL: match duplicate IPv6 subnet prefix

Tags: mysql, analytics, ipv6, subnet

I have issues finding the right approach to properly return (and match) the first /64 bits of IPv6 addresses stored in the DB like:  2a02:a420:0003:7dbc:0002:0001:b693:9622

I need to retrieve entries in the table that are using the same network/subnet of IPv6 (/64 bits)

note: the table includes both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

i am using MySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: What datatype do you use to store your ipv6 addresses?

Comment: Datatype used is VARCHAR(50)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `addrcolumn` stored as a VARCHAR(39) text string with IPv6 addresses, and you have @matchaddr as a text string containing a *valid address within the /64 range you want to match.*

You can get the first 16 hex digits  of `addrcolumn` like this:

```
    SUBSTRING(HEX(INET6_ATON(addrcolumn)),1,16)
```

So you can do your match with the LIKE operator like this.

```
WHERE      HEX(INET6_ATON(addrcolumn)) 
      LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(HEX(INET6_ATON(@matchaddr)),1,16), '%')
```

After the string-manipulation functions this comes out looking like

```
WHERE `2a02a42000037dbc00020001b693962a' LIKE '2a02a42000037dbc%'
```

You need the mischegoss with the [INET6_ATON()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) because IPv6 addresses are often shortened with two colons meaning a bunch of zeros like this:

```
 2a02:a420::2:1:b693:9622
```

[INET6_ATON()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) copes with that correctly.

**Edit** But, if you assume your representation of ipv6 addresses never, *ever*, contains any shortening via `:` or `:1:2:` style abbreviation, you can just do substring matching with LIKE.

```
WHERE addrcolumn LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@matchaddr)),1,19), '%')
```

Note the 19-character substring. This comes out looking like

```
WHERE `2a02:a420:0003:7dbc:0002:0001:b693:962a'
 LIKE '2a02:a420:0003:7dbc%'
```

Beware: real users will violate your assumption.

In MySQL 8+ you can turn a binary representation into an unabbreviated text representation like this:

```
 SELECT ​LOWER(
    ​SUBSTRING(
       ​REGEXP_REPLACE(HEX(binaryAddr), '([0-9a-f]{4})', '$1:'), 1, 39))
```

In MariaDB 10+ it is:

```
 SELECT ​LOWER(
    ​SUBSTRING(
       ​REGEXP_REPLACE(HEX(binaryAddr), '([0-9a-f]{4})', '\\1:'), 1, 39))
```

Will the MariaDB or MySQL team add some IPv6-specific indexing / filtering stuff one day? It would be very nice if they did.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your help i'm way closer to what i need to achieve
I see my question was not clear enough, my mistake ;) 

The viewer using the DB can only cope with 2a02:a420:0003:7dbc as input and not with shortened IPv6 addresses 


select  SUBSTRING(HEX(INET6_ATON(IPADRES)),1,16) as subtring_ipv6, count(SUBSTRING(HEX(INET6_ATON(IPADRES)),1,16)) as count_subtring_ipv6 from orders
where YMD >= '2021-01-01'
and is_ipv6(IPADRES) = 1
group by SUBSTRING(HEX(INET6_ATON(IPADRES)),1,16);

The syntax above returns the shortened version, is there a way to have it return not shortened?